# Xmldsig signature on SOAP message

Tags: java, xml, soap, cxf

My code look like this:

```
MyService f = new MyService();
MyPortType type = f.getMyPortType();
```

I need to sign soap request with x509 certificate
so as far as I know I need to use

```
 XmlSigOutInterceptor
```

but I get strange errors that document cannot be found?

Comment: That is very vague, you should provide a minimal example.

Comment: Not sure where to start. I have created classes with java2wsdl. Methods that do not required signature work, but those with signature are signed with ws-security namespace in the header although service is expecting xmldsig in the body..